# AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute <class that I defined inside settings.py> when settings imported from conf

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I've added `enum` in the `settings.py` file

```
class Syncs(Enum):
    A = 'a'
    B = 'b'
```

when I try to use them in an app by importing `from django.conf import settings`, it raises:

```
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute Syncs
```

on the other hand if I import settings file directly it works

I know it's because `from django.conf import settings` works differently so that's why this doesn't work.
Is there some recommended way to do this?

So far I do:

```
class Syncs(Enum):
    A = 'a'
    B = 'b'

SYNCS = Syncs
```

Comment: Django ignores names that are not ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES in the settings file. Could just move the enum to a different file and import from there?

Comment: It will indeed only populate items in uppercase: https://github.com/django/django/blob/604fadde11966c5fdfe5a236a7a3963ee868f764/django/conf/__init__.py#L184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, the `settings` object is a *lazy* object that gets populate from the settings module. It will only populate with items that are written in uppercase (can be with punctuations like an underscore). Indeed, the source [code that populates the items <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.1/django/conf/__init__.py#L183-L185) says:

> ```
> for setting in dir(global_settings):
>     if setting.isupper():
>         setattr(self, setting, getattr(global_settings, setting))
> ```

It will thus check if the setting satisfies the [**`str.isupper()`** method <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper), if that is the case, it is added to the object, otherwise it is not. So you will need to define this in all-caps. The rationale behind it is likely that settings are constants, and in Python the convention is that constants are written in all-caps snake-case.

You can define the enum as:

```
class SYNCS(Enum):
    A = 'a'
    B = 'b'
```

But it makes me wondering why you want to define an enum in the settings, this is a bit "*odd*".

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense, thank you. I didn't know about the upper case rule at all. Yes, maybe it's not the best place to define the class but it's a global variable that should be accessible from anywhere so I decided to put it there.